# Django fails at sending e-mail in production but works in develoment

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I have a django app running in google cloud that sends emails through gmail in production and development, but when I added a new app to the project, using another gmail account, it works in development, but not in production, which is really weird.

**Production settings (base.py)**

```
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_HOST_USER_MED = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER_MED')
EMAIL_HOST_PSSWD_MED = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PSSWD_MED')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**Sending email function for not working app**

```
def email(pedido):
    conexion = get_connection()
    conexion.password = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PSSWD_MED
    conexion.username = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER_MED

    asunto = f'Solicitud pedido {pedido.codigo}'
    remitente = f'Lab_C403'
    destinatario = [pedido.proveedor.contacto]
    html_message = render_to_string(
        'email_medicina.html',
        {'pedido': pedido, 'saludo': saludo}
    )
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
    send_mail(
        asunto,
        plain_message,
        remitente,
        destinatario,
        html_message=html_message,
        connection=conexion,
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

As you can see, I change the email account and the password for it. Weirdly it works in development but not in production. I don't think gmail is blocking my server IP since it's a google's server. Also the other app using the default settings works.

**EDIT: This is the error I'm getting:**

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /medicina/

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError r2sm3319014wrg.68 - gsmtp', '=?utf-8?q?Lab=5FC403?=')
```

**This is my development settings file:**

```
from inventario.settings.base import *

DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email1'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'psswd2'
EMAIL_HOST_USER_MED = 'email2'
EMAIL_HOST_PSSWD_MED = 'psswd2'
```

Any help guys?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks good, so any error messages / logs?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this without any error messages or logs. Can you confirm the environment variables are correct in production? You may want to  remove `fail_silently=False` to generate more useful debug output.

Comment: Hi guys, I edited the post with more info, sorry for that. Variables are working fine indeed. I also changed the account to "2-step verification" and used a gmail application password. My guess is that something in the production settings is preventing the loading of these variables. I can't understand why one mail works and another doesn't

Comment: Any help guys? :) This is driving me crazy, the whole app works ecept for that thing and is already deployed...@rob

Comment: Hi @jpm92 did you manage to solve this? Grateful for a reply.

Comment: Hi @oktested, I just restarted the production server and everything worked. I will never know what was happening, but I'd suggest you do the same. Cheers!